# Setting the logging to Elasticsearch using python-elasticsearch-extension in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

I need to log the AWS lambda logs to AWS Elasticsearch(ES) domain. By default, logs are pushed to Cloudwatch. Instead of sending the logs to CloudWatch, have to send to ES using [python-example-elasticsearch-extension](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-extensions/tree/main/python-example-elasticsearch-extension)

To achieve this, have added the elasticsearch extension to lambda layers and added the layer in the lambda function. When the extension is imported in the lambda function, it's working but not able to see logs in the Elasticsearch. In the documentation, adding the extension and ES_ENDPOINT and ES_INDEX should log the lambda logs to ES but not working.

How to set the logger in lambda using the Elasticsearch extension to use LogsExtensionAPI to stream logs to Elasticsearch instead of Cloudwatch.

**Lambda code:**

```
import json
import extensions.logs_api_elasticsearch_extension as logs_api_elasticsearch_extension
elogger = logs_api_elasticsearch_extension()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        print("[info] test esext")
    except Exception as e:
        print("[error] test esext")
```

**Execution Results:**

```
   Function Logs
    START RequestId: 47d30bec-8b9b-4fb6-ae45-41952f1a5d66 Version: $LATEST
    Starting Extensions {'events': ['INVOKE', 'SHUTDOWN']} {'destination': {'protocol': 'HTTP', 'URI': 'http://sandbox:4243'}, 'types': ['platform', 'function'], 'buffering': {'timeoutMs': 1000, 'maxBytes': 262144, 'maxItems': 10000}}
    Initializing LogsAPIExternalExtension logs_api_elasticsearch_extension.py
    Registering to ExtensionsAPIClient on http://127.0.0.1:9001/2020-01-01/extension
    Initializing HTTP Server on 0.0.0.0:4243
    Subscribing to Logs API on http://127.0.0.1:9001/2020-08-15
    Successfully subscribed to Logs API: b'"AlreadySubscribed"'
    Serving LogsAPIHTTPExternalExtension logs_api_elasticsearch_extension.py
    Serving HTTP Server on 0.0.0.0:4243
    166.255.279.10 - - [02/Feb/2021 09:12:52] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    166.255.279.10 - - [02/Feb/2021 09:12:52] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    [ERROR] TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
        return load_source(name, filename, file)
      File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
        module = _load(spec)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 7, in <module>
        elogger = logs_api_elasticsearch_extension()EXTENSION   Name: logs_api_elasticsearch_extension.py   State: Ready    Events: [INVOKE,SHUTDOWN]
    Received response from ExtensionsAPIClient: b'{"eventType":"SHUTDOWN","deadlineMs":1612257175241,"shutdownReason":"failure"}'
    166.255.279.10 - - [02/Feb/2021 09:12:53] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    END RequestId: 47d30bec-8b9d-4fb6-ae45-41952f1a5d66
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda function and AWS Elastic search cluster should be in same VPC or having proper connectivity through vpc peering. elastic search cluster shod accessible from lambda function.

Below is the screenshot for the elastic search cluster where you can mention whether it's a publicly accessible stack or not.

[image]

Below is the screenshot for AWS Lambda for VPC settings.

[image]

check AWS IAM policies for leastic search access.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/anonymous-not-authorized-elasticsearch/
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/es-troubleshoot-cloudwatch-logs/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html

Comment: roles are assigned for the lambda function to access ES domain. are you saying this error is due to permission issues.

Comment: for testing purposes can you please try to send some logs from cloudwatch logs to ES. and check the elastic search access policy: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html

Comment: Make sense, will send CloudWatch logs to ES.